# Alternative to mpirun inside python script

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I'm facing this curious issue. I don't think the answer is difficult but I can't find it anywhere so I rely on your suggestions.

Suppose I have a parallel python function inside file `parallel_func.py`:

```
    def parallel_func():

      parser=OptionParser()
      parser.add_option("-f", "--file",       dest="filename",
                          help="Input FILE", metavar="FILE")
      parser.add_option("--parallel", action="store_true",
                          help="Specify if we need to initialize MPI", 
                          dest="with_MPI", default=False)
      (options, args)=parser.parse_args()

      if options.with_MPI == True:
         from mpi4py import MPI  
         comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
         myid = comm.Get_rank()
         numberPart = comm.Get_size()
         have_MPI = True
     else:
         comm = 0
         myid = 0
         numberPart = 1
         have_MPI = False
    etc. etc.
```

I can call this function from the shell simply typing:

> mpirun -np XX parallel_func.py  -f input_file   --parallel

Now, is there a way to call my parallel_func as a function inside a python script which is not parallel and run in single core? My current version works but only run parallel_func in single core:

```
from parallel_func.py import parallel_func
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Main
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

def main():

  parser=OptionParser()
  parser.add_option("-f", "--file",       dest="filename",
                      help="Input FILE", metavar="FILE")
  parser.add_option("-n", "--partitions", dest="partitions", 
                      default=1,
                      help="number of PARTITIONS", 
                      metavar="PARTITIONS")                                            

  (options, args)=parser.parse_args()
  options.partitions  = int( options.partitions )  

  if options.partitions > 1:
     options.with_MPI = True
  else:
     options.with_MPI = False

  parallel_func(options)
```

Long story short, is there a way I can communicate within the python function `main` all the info required for `MPI.COMM_WORLD` to make `parallel_func` work properly?

Thanks in advance for the answer!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for dynamic process management. This means you *spawn* some processes from the single process and they form a communicator. You can find an [example here](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#dynamic-process-management). There are several drawbacks to this approach:

- You need to provide a special script or entry point for the launched process - you cannot just resume at the point of the call to spawn
- The spawned processes are in an inter-communicator containing two separate groups (the parent and the spawned processes). They are different to use than your normal (intra-communicator).
- Some HPC systems / batch systems do not support MPI process spawning

Take this into account when evaluating how you design your application.